# Flutter Why is container width not honoured?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a circle image. Unfortunately, the width of the container is not honoured and I can't figure out why. What am I missing?

[image]

```
Drawer _getDrawer(List<Job> data) {
  return Drawer(
    // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
    // through the options in the Drawer if there isn't enough vertical
    // space to fit everything.
    child: ListView(
      // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        _getDrawerHeader(),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Item 1'),
          onTap: () {
            // Update the state of the app
            // ...
          },
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Item 2'),
          onTap: () {
            // Update the state of the app
            // ...
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

DrawerHeader _getDrawerHeader() {
  return DrawerHeader(
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().asStream(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                _getCircleImage(snapshot.data.photoUrl),
                Text('test'),
                Text('test'),
              ],
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  );
}

_getCircleImage(String url) {
  return Container(
    width: 64.0,
    height: 64.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new NetworkImage(url),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It seems the image is causing the distortion. I don't know why though. Putting the entire container inside of a CircleAvatar as a child weirdly solves the issue. But directly applying the image as backgroundImage to the Circle Avatar is not working either.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

That's a little tricky but it's how Flutter works, your `Container` doesn't know the constraints of the Parent, then It try to fill all the space available.

You can fix it adding an `Align` Widget

```
    _getCircleImage(String url) {
      return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Container(
          width: 64.0,
          height: 64.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new NetworkImage(url),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

More info : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

Comment: That doesn't corospond with the tldr. "tl;dr: Container tries, in order: to honor alignment, to size itself to the child, to honor the width, height, and constraints, to expand to fit the parent, to be as small as possible." Here it states that it honours the width before matching the parent container.

Comment: I think this is the case:  If the widget has no child, no height, no width, no constraints, and no alignment, but the parent provides bounded constraints, then Container expands to fit the constraints provided by the parent.

Comment: you can simply use the alignment parameter of the container :)

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:**

`Container`'s constraints wont' have any impact if the passed constraints were tight.

For example:

```dart
SizedBox.fromSize(
  size: Size.fromRadius(100), // Tight constraints are passed to the Container below
  child: Container(
    width: 100, // No impact
    height: 100, // No impact
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
)
```

---

**Solutions:**

You need to loose those tight constraints. There are multiple ways of doing it. I'm listing a few here:

1. Use `UnconstrainedBox`:

   ```dart
   SizedBox.fromSize(
     size: Size.fromRadius(100),
     child: UnconstrainedBox( // <-- UnconstrainedBox
       child: Container(
         width: 100, // Works
         height: 100, // Works
         color: Colors.blue,
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```
2. Use `Center` or `Align`:

   ```dart
   SizedBox.fromSize(
     size: Size.fromRadius(100),
     child: Center( //    <-- Center
       child: Container(
         width: 100, // Works
         height: 100, // Works
         color: Colors.blue,
       ),
     ),
   )
   ```
3. Use a `Column` or better `Wrap`:

   ```dart
   SizedBox.fromSize(
     size: Size.fromRadius(100),
     child: Wrap( //   <-- Wrap
       children: [
         Container(
           width: 100, // Works
           height: 100, // Works
           color: Colors.blue,
         ),
       ],
     ),
   )
   ```