# Flutter fitting image in container without stretching

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the following code but my image is stretching, regardless of the box fit value. Need help in making it fill the screen without stretching.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => _optionsDialogBox(),
              child: Container(
                height: 250.0,
                child: _companyLogo == null
                    ? CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 75.0,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.camera_alt,
                          size: 75.0,
                        ),
                      )
                    : Image.memory(
                        base64Decode(_companyLogo),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                        blurRadius: 5.0,
                        spreadRadius: 1.0)
                  ],
                  color: constructionOrange,
//              gradient: GRADIENT,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter Why is container width not honoured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225462/flutter-why-is-container-width-not-honoured)

Comment: I just encounter the same issue, but got fix with the above post.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to flutter but I have a logic in mind that can solve this: 
let size of image be = w (width) * h (height) 
let max size of container be = a (cont. width) * b (cont. height) 
find the a/w and then multiply by h such that the size of new image will be a * (h*a/w)